# CURL Command Line URL Parameters

Tags: http, curl

I am trying to send a `DELETE` request with a url parameter using CURL. I am doing:

```
curl -H application/x-www-form-urlencoded -X DELETE http://localhost:5000/locations` -d 'id=3'
```

However, the server is not seeing the parameter id = 3. I tried using some GUI application and when I pass the url as: `http://localhost:5000/locations?id=3`, it works. I really would rather use CURL rather than this GUI application. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 407, accepted):

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Content-type header is not required (well, kinda depends).   Unless the request handler expects parameters coming from the form body.   Try it out:

```
curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:5000/locations?id=3"
```

or

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:5000/locations?id=3"
```

Comment: It worked. I just realised the URL has to be between quotes to accept parameters. That MIME type is for a URL with parameters and thats what the GUI application uses. Also, I do not want to do `GET`. I want to `DELETE` and not `GET` and I am trying to follow proper REST design standards so I am using DELETE and not GET when deleting.

Comment: In my case it works only with double quotation, with single quotation in says 
curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
But with "" quotation works just fine.

Comment: I am actually on Windows environment. Using single quotes didn't work for me. It thrown an error like " 'http" not supported. However it worked when I included them within double quotes.

Answer (score 242):

[@Felipsmartins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262820) is correct.

It is worth mentioning that it is because you cannot really use the -d/--data option if this is not a POST request. But this is still possible if you use the -G option.

Which means you can do this:

```
curl -X DELETE -G 'http://localhost:5000/locations' -d 'id=3'
```

Here it is a bit silly but when you are on the command line and you have a lot of parameters, it is a lot tidier.

I am saying this because cURL commands are usually quite long, so it is worth making it on more than one line escaping the line breaks.

```
curl -X DELETE -G \
'http://localhost:5000/locations' \
-d id=3 \
-d name=Mario \
-d surname=Bros
```

This is obviously a lot more comfortable if you use zsh. I mean when you need to re-edit the previous command because zsh lets you go line by line. (just saying)

Comment: Life saver!  Thanks man!  I have a script where I want to use --data-urlencode on a GET.  This made it so I don't have to manually url-encode my parameters.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you implying that -X DELETE -G is really a POST request?

Comment: ` -G, --get           Put the post data in the URL and use GET` 
No, it just adds the post data to the url, -X [method] takes precedence
(source: curl --help and experience)

Comment: How can this be so convoluted. One could assume `--data-urlencode`  adds the data to the URL with no exceptions but now you need to combine it with `--get` to make it actually work.

Comment: zsh isn't really necessary, try the `fc` command - it puts the previous command into your editor, when you save and quit, it runs the command.