# Delete document using findOneAndRemove Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug, node.js-connect

I am receiving this error when trying to delete a document from the database:

> Cannot GET /delete/532fa5e56f885c7fec5223b1fds

How can I successfully delete the document?

app.js

```
//Delete 
app.del('/delete/:id', routes.delete_offer);
```

routes/index.js

```
    //Delete
    exports.delete_offer = function (req,res){
      Offer.findOneAndRemove({'_id' : req.params.id}, function (err,offer){
        res.redirect('/newsfeed');
      });
    };
```

views/dashboard.jade

```
        - each offer in offers
            div.offer.row
                a(href="/offer/" + offer._id)
                    div.columns
                        div.sell_type
                            p=offer.type
                    div.small-8.columns.sell_info
                        p.sell_price="$" + offer.fixedPrice() + " "
                        p.sell_location="@ " + offer.location + " ›"
                    div.small-4.columns.sell_pic
                        p=offer.user_id
                a.delete(href="/delete/" + offer._id)="Delete Offer"
```

Comment: Is not the error message enough? Your route requires a **DELETE** verb. You are trying to use **GET**. See [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters) for a start.

Comment: make sure that you are actually posting to the route. if you are using browser to navigate to that route, it will actually make a get request. use postman to verify the api.

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP verb your using is not correct
use `app.delete("/delete/:id", routes.delete_offer);`

I think that should work. Cause I don't think there is no **del** method in the HTTP verb for express.js framework it mostly *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE* plus a few others.

Comment: `Cannot GET /delete/532fa5e56f885c7fec5223b1fds` You'll also have to use DELETE instead of GET wherever you're calling it from.

Answer (score 3):

If you using mongoose. You can fix file routes/index.js.

```
//Delete
exports.delete_offer = function (req,res){
  Offer.findOneAndRemove({_id : new mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)}, function (err,offer){
    res.redirect('/newsfeed');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a route set up for a **DELETE** verb in a RESTful sense. You don't seem to be calling it that way or using it in a RESTful way.

You application should **really** be handling this as a **REST** request, and issue status and content back as the response appropriate to what happened. Right now you are re-directing to another URL. That is not the correct approach. But If you just do not understand REST, then do it that way, but change your **route** to use **GET** instead.

For what it is worth, once you have sorted out your usage and testing, possibly using curl or similar as was [**shown**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters). Then perhaps consider using [`.findByIdAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove) instead.

```
Offer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err,offer){
    if(err) { throw err; }
    // ...
}
```

And then actually checking the response is what you expect before just forwarding or sending a valid or error response. Which is what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Notice if you use the Mongoose `findByIdAndRemove` function to retrieve and delete the object from the `Model`.

```
exports.delete_offer = function(req, res) {

    Offer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        else
            res.json({ message: 'Offer Deleted!'});
    });
}
```