# submitting post request to curl

Tags: php, curl, indoor-positioning-system

Im totally new in using curl or other submission services. As i'm following this [link](https://github.com/wrld3d/wrld-indoor-maps-api/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) to submit an indoor map using wrld3d api they've stated the following line in order to submit a post request

```
$ curl -v -XPOST https://indoor-maps-api.wrld3d.com/v1/edits/?token=dev_auth_token -F name="my venue name" -F venue_street_address="<address>" -F venue_phone_number="<phone no.>" -F venue_email="<email address>" -F submission_contact_email="<email address for notifications>" -F venue_outline="@/path/to/my/file"
```

I tried filling in the values such as dev_auth_token with my respective account's developer token  and other values like "my venue name","".. etc  but i guess im going wrong as the command isn't running.Is there any syntax to follow? Here is how i filled up the command [image: Command] and here is the command after executing [image]

Answer (score 1):

When your URI contains some data wrap it with double quota

```
$ curl -v -X POST "https://indoor-maps-api.wrld3d.com/v1/edits/?token=dev_auth_token&name=my venue name&venue_street_address=<address>&venue_phone_number=<phone no.>&venue_email=<email address>&submission_contact_email=<email address for notifications>&venue_outline=@/path/to/my/file"
```

Same here: [CURL Command Line URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters). You have just trouble with parameters. Also, ... you can try with your command but using -d (that stay for data) instead of -F.

- -F, --form
- (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type  multipart/form-data  according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a  file get attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
- Example: to send an image to a server, where 'profile' is the name of the form-field to which portrait.jpg will be the input:

  - curl -F profile=@portrait.jpg https://example.com/upload.cgi
  - To  read  content  from stdin instead of a file, use - as the filename. This goes for both @ and < constructs. Unfortunately it does not support reading the file from a named pipe or similar, as it needs the full size before the transfer starts.
  - You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', in a manner similar to:

    - curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" example.com
      or
    - curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" example.com
  - You can also explicitly change the name field of a file upload part by setting filename=, like this:

    - curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" example.com
  - If filename/path contains ',' or ';', it must be quoted by double-quotes like:

    - curl -F "file=@\"localfile\";filename=\"nameinpost\"" example.com
      or
    - curl -F 'file=@"localfile";filename="nameinpost"' example.com
  - Note that if a filename/path is quoted by double-quotes, any double-quote or backslash within the filename must be escaped by backslash.
  - See further examples and details in the MANUAL.
  - This option can be used multiple times.
  - This option overrides -d, --data and -I, --head and --upload.

Comment: i got the following errors `token is not recognized an internal or external command,operable program or hatch file`  &  `venue_street_address is not recognized an internal or external command,operable program or hatch file`

Comment: Actually i didn't understand much would you please give me an example of how to write the command?

Comment: Thats how i wrote it: `curl -k -X POST "https://indoor-maps-api.wrld3d.com/v1/edits/?put=token&"5919cd32ec96a905c3f8ad2ae21a5548f2073e0e53d68ec33fd4e034b391102432474eea6438fc35"-F name="myhome" -F venue_street_address="egypt" -F venue_phone_number="00201011854060" -F venue_email="iahmedwael@gmail.com" -F submission_contact_email="iahmedwael@gmail.com" -F venue_outline="C:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\myhomeindoormap"" `