# MultiPart PUT request not working in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, curl, kotlin

I have the following curl request

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:50005/did:corda:tcn:77ccbf5e-4ddd-4092-b813-ac06084a3eb0  -H 'content-type:multipart/form-data'  -F 'instruction=hgfhhf'
```

I am trying to read the instruction in my spring boot controller as seen below

```
@PutMapping(value = "{id}",
    produces = arrayOf(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE),
    consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))

fun createID(@PathVariable(value = "id") id: String,
    @RequestParam("instruction") instruction: String ) : ResponseEntity<Any?>
```

But the code above returns

```
"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'instruction' is not present"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. remove unused:

   ```
   consumes = arrayOf(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
   ```
2. you have missed request param **instruction** (in reqeust), try this:

   ```sh
   curl -X PUT -G 'http://localhost:50005/did:corda:tcn:77ccbf5e-4ddd-4092-b813-ac06084a3eb0' -d 'instruction=hgfhhf'
   ```

   also take a look at [CURL Command Line URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters)