# cURL certain links unsuccessful

Tags: php, curl

I want to use script to download file daily.

This work perfectly on some links,

curl -kL http://kodimalaysia.com/m3u/176b8-ujwsej.xml.gz -o /volume1/docker/webgrabplus/data/mysg.xml.gz

However the command line not working with links with username and password.

Example:
http://livegopanel.club:8080/xmltv.php?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD

In my script I will put multiple links to download.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This SO question and answer may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters

Comment: Thank you.  It solved.

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CURL Command Line URL Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371284/curl-command-line-url-parameters)

Comment: Yes. I able to use the script to download.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add double quotes between the link, then it will download the files.